# Ошибка String index out of range

Tags: java, android

Все работает когда я передаю строку формата *25 янв. - 25 февр.*, то есть без года. Когда передаю строку уже с годом (25 янв. 2020 г. - 25 февр. 2021 г.), то получаю ошибку 
`Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -12`. Подскажите, что я делаю не так.

```
    //Получение даты начала
public Date getFirst() throws ParseException {
    String firstDate;
    //Для даты без года
    if (headerText.length() <= 19)
        firstDate = new String(headerText.substring(0, headerText.indexOf(".")) + " " + getCurrentYear());
    //Для даты с годом
    else
        firstDate = new String(headerText.substring(0, headerText.indexOf(".")) +
                headerText.substring(headerText.indexOf(".") + 1, headerText.indexOf("-") - 4));
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");

    return formatter.parse(firstDate);
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что на вход подается именно указанная в вопросе строка?
У меня Ваш код полностью корректно отработал

Comment: Где-то выход за пределы строки. Добавьте полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка `править` под вопросом)

Comment: Ошибка не здесь. В этом коде вообще не может возникнуть доступ по индексу -12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была очень смешная, на вход подавалась дата не с символом "-", а с "–". Не знал, что бывают разные тире.